# BigQuery Script with IF and While

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, google-bigquery

I need to make a scrip to search a Regex in a table and paste the result of all regex in other table.
Problems: Some columns exist null and this breaks the query.
The column 1 never null.
The column 2 some nulls.
The column 3 with alot of nulls.

When column 2 is null the column 3 is also null.

The query I made so far. When is not null works perfecly.

```
declare I int64;
set N1 = (select count(*) from `table_1`);
set I = 1;

while I <= N1 do

                    
            INSERT `table_2` (eventAction, eventCateroy, eventLabel, Rotulo,   Produto)
            select
            distinct(h.eventInfo.eventAction) as eventAction,
                
            h.eventInfo.eventCategory,
            h.eventInfo.eventLabel,
            (case
                    when I=I then (select Rotulo from `table_1` where Cod=I) 
                end) as Rotulo,
            (case
                    when I=I then (select Produto from `table_1` where Cod=I) 
                end) as Produto
            from `table_3` t, UNNEST(hits) as h
                where REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.eventInfo.eventAction, (Select eventAction from `table_1` where Cod=i))
                and h.eventInfo.eventCategory = (Select eventCategory from `table_1` where Cod=i);
                and REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.eventInfo.eventLabel, (Select eventLabel from `table_1` where Cod=i))
Set I=I+1;
end while;
```

What I need

```
declare N1 int64;
declare I int64;
set N1 = (select count(*) from `table_1`);
set I = 1;

while I <= N1 do

If eventLabel from table_1 = null
  (Insert Query Without eventLabel column)
    if eventAction from table_1 = null
      (insert query withou eventLabel and eventAction)
else 
   (query with all columns)
Set I=I+1;
end while;
```

I didnt find how to write this code.

Comment: I don't think using loop is correct approach here (not to mention even $ost of such execution) and looks like it can be done in "simple" set-based way - meaning with just one query. I suggest you to present your use case with input data examples and expected output along with logic to be applied :o)

Answer (score 0):

Its very hard to answer this question without examples of the input data and the expected output but you should be able to solve this issue using just SQL, let me know if this helps:

```
WITH A as (
SELECT
  eventAction,
  eventCategory,
  eventLabel,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as Iterator,
FROM `table_1`
),
B AS (
SELECT *,
ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * FROM `table_3` t, UNNEST(hits) as h
                where REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.eventInfo.eventAction, A.eventAction)
                and h.eventInfo.eventCategory = A.eventCategory
                and REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.eventInfo.eventLabel, A.event_Label)) as table_3_column,
FROM A)

SELECT *,
CASE 
  WHEN IFNULL(some_column) then Rotulo
  WHEN IFNULL(some_othercolumn) THEN Produto
END AS something_else
FROM B, unnest (table_3_column)
```